# How do new lines work in textarea with php?

Tags: php, textarea, newline

I am creating a news publishing website and the only thing I can't do in the site is enter and show new-line.

There is a textarea in the site to write articles, if I press ENTER while I am typing, it will take me into a new line, but after having submitted all, and make query to mysql to pull and echo what I had typed in, the new line does not show up. All texts are next to each other. So, I was wondering if i could input and output newlines in textarea with the help of PHP?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. But, I have a simple textarea input and then, sql query to submitted the data, into Database. I am not using anything else.

Comment: You mean that those new line characters are disappearing?

Comment: Yes, when I make query and echo back the data from DB, there is absolutely no-lines. It just makes new lines when it reached the width limit of the div. But, I checked the DB, there are newlines in the tables but no <br/> </p> or even \n.

Comment: Well, if you are outputting the text to div, you must replace the `\n` with `<br/>`, or split the text with newline character and wrap it within those `<p>` and `</p>` tags. As Quentin said in his answer below. E.g. like this: `echo str_replace("\n",'<br/>',$text);`

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for keeping up with this question, but since I am newbie I have taken screen copy of the images here.
http://imm.io/Gcda

Comment: Ok, imho you can try to replace the `$row[c_comment]` with `".htmlspecialchars(str_replace("\n",'<br/>',$row[c_comment]))."`  or maybe `".str_replace("\n",'<br/>',htmlspecialchars($row[c_comment]))."` or maybe just `".str_replace("\n",'<br/>',$row[c_comment])."`

Comment: Awesome! The second one worked. I was just looking for another solution, before your solution, and I got b12br. So, since both of them work, which one is more recommended or stable? Because, from now on, I will be needing this a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I am also glad it helped and think the `nl2br` is probably faster than `str_replace` and so recommended as Quentin said :-) Have a good time!

Comment: nl2br (which I suggested in my answer) does the same thing as `str_replace("\n",'<br/>', $input)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submit a form, you are submitting **text**.

When you put that text into an HTML document, it is **HTML**.

In HTML a new line is just a piece of white space with the same significance as a space or a tab.

If you want new lines to show up, then you need to with wrap them with markup that causes them to be rendered (such as a `<pre>` element or an element with the `white-space` property set to cause them to render) or you need to replace them with suitable markup.

A very primitive replacement would be PHP's [`nl2br` function](http://php.net/nl2br). A more advanced option would generate `<p>` elements and treat different numbers of sequential new lines differently (e.g. a [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) parser such as the one used by Stackoverflow).

Comment: That is why I am asking for help.

Comment: Hi, I think you don't understand my problem. But, I have uploaded this image to describe it very well. If you can, please take a look and tell me what you think. http://imm.io/Gcda

Comment: No, I understood the question perfectly.